# Select de registros hasta sumar un valor dado

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito una función que liste los registros de una tabla hasta que la suma del campo *importe* contenga al monto de la variable *$total*.

```
public function listar($codigo, $total) {
  try {
      $sql = "SELECT id, importe FROM ctacte WHERE codigo = :codigo";  <-- QUE DEBO AGREGAR?
      $bd = new ConexionDB();
      $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindParam(':total', $total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
```

He creado una tabla ejemplo para los datos: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9839a5e/1)
Los totales son:

```
11->50
22->70
33->8
44->35
55->35
```

Por ejemplo en la función listar($codigo, $total) si ingresa el $codigo=11 y $total=50.
La función debe listar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pues la suma de los importes listados es 67, esto incluye a 50.

Si `$total` fuera 32. solamente mostraría los dos primeros registros.

Si ingresa el $codigo=44 y $total=35.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pues la suma de los importes listados es 52, esto incluye a 35.

Agradeceré alguna ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes crear una consulta que vaya sumando de forma acumulativa hasta alcanzar un valor dado (`50` u otro).

He aquí un fiddle de ejemplo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE ctacte (
  id int(10) NOT NULL primary key,
  codigo int(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  importe decimal(8,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ctacte (id, codigo, importe) VALUES
(1, 11, 20),
(2, 22, 30),
(3, 11, 12),
(4, 33, 10),
(5, 22, 8),
(6, 44, 12),
(7, 11, 15),
(8, 11, 20),
(9, 22, 42),
(10, 33, 30),
(11, 11, 24),
(12, 44, 40),
(13, 55, 35),
(14, 22, 10),
(15, 33, 12),
(16, 44, 13),
(17, 55, 16);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET @sum := 0;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t.*, 
      (@sum := @sum + importe) as total
     FROM ctacte t 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) AS crossjoin
     WHERE t.codigo=11
     ORDER BY id 
   ) t
WHERE 
  total < 50 
  OR (total >= 50 and total - importe < 50);
```

| id | codigo | importe | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 20.00 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 11 | 12.00 | 32.00 |
| 7 | 11 | 15.00 | 47.00 |
| 8 | 11 | 20.00 | 67.00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/59z5cU9o1YSM5P3NkzGSge/0)

Lo único es que debemos definir la variable `@sum` desde PDO, pero eso no es problema. Veamos:

```
public function listar($codigo, $total) {
    try {
            $bd = new ConexionDB();
            $bd->prepare("SET @sum := 0;")->execute();
            $sql = "SELECT t.*
                        FROM 
                        (
                            SELECT 
                            t.*, 
                            (@sum := @sum + importe) as total
                            FROM ctacte t 
                            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) AS crossjoin
                            WHERE t.codigo=:codigo
                            ORDER BY id 
                        ) t
                        WHERE 
                        total < :paramA 
                        OR (total >= :paramB AND total - importe < :paramC)";
            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':paramA', $total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':paramB', $total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':paramC', $total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d%s",$row['id'],$row['codigo'],$row['importe'],$row['total'],PHP_EOL);
            }
    } // ... fin del try
```

La salida debe ser lo mismo que ves en la tabla más arriba, al final del fiddle.

---

#### @deprecated

Tú puedes usar `GROUP_CONCAT` para agrupar los `ids` y los `importes`, agregando además un criterio con `HAVING` para que sólo traiga filas cuando el criterio se cumpla. Luego, te valdrás de `explode` para ir sumando los importes hasta llegar al límite de `$total`.

El código quedaría así:

```
public function listar($codigo, $total) {
  try {
      $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids, codigo, GROUP_CONCAT(importe) AS importes, SUM(importe) AS total FROM ctacte  WHERE codigo = :codigo  GROUP BY codigo HAVING SUM(importe) > :total; ";
      $bd = new ConexionDB();
      $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindParam(':total', $total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $importes=explode(",",$row['importes']);
      $ids=explode(",",$row['ids']);
      $sum=0;
      foreach ($importes as $k=>$v){
          $sum+=$v;
           printf("%d\t%d\t%d%s",$ids[$k],$row['codigo'],$sum,PHP_EOL);
          if($sum>$total){
              break;
          }
      }
```

En el caso (11,50) este código te imprimirá esto en pantalla:

```
1   11  20
3   11  32
7   11  47
8   11  67
```

Perfecto, eso es lo que quieres al parecer ... pero aquí hay un error de planteamiento o de diseño en alguna parte. Trajimos un valor para desecharlo y eso no está bien. Me refiero al id `11`  y al importe `24`. ¿Qué es lo que justifica que se desechen datos? ¿Acaso no convendría repensar tu diseño o la lógica de tu programa?

Comment: Al poner `importe <= :total` solamente estoy condicionando por un solo registro, y debería sumar. Algo como `sum(importe)<= :total`.

Comment: @Puntay pues eso no queda claro en la pregunta. Hablas de *listar* las filas que cumplan esa condición, e incluso pones un ejemplo de lista de resultados. Por favor, edita la pregunta y aclara eso. Además, no tienes ningún `SUM` en tu instrucción SQL.

Comment: Edité la pregunta, pensé que estaba claro al momento de listar los ejemplos, pues no se listan todos. Solamente hasta que la suma del campo `importe` contenga al valor ingresado en la variable `$total`.

Comment: @Puntay aún es confuso (sobre todo el resultado final que esperas y el uso que darás a esos resultados). Prueba esta consulta en tu [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9839a5e/1): **`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids, codigo, GROUP_CONCAT(importe) AS importes, SUM(importe) AS total FROM ctacte  WHERE codigo=11 HAVING SUM(importe) > 50;`** Te arrojará los `ids` y los `importes` agrupados y separados por coma y un total de `91`. ¿Ese es el resultado esperado para el caso (11, 50)? ¿Piensas usar cada `id` y cada `importe` como una fila por separado además? ¿El resultado de ids debe detenerse?

Comment: Para el caso (11, 50) solamente debe mostrar 4 registros. Y si, voy a usar el id y el importe. El resultado de los ids debe deternerse cuando la suma del campo `importe` supere o sea igual a `$total`.

Comment: @Puntay ¿por qué cuatro y no más? Esas cosas que son quisquillosas deben quedar expuestas con claridad en la pregunta. Y además, ¿qué cuatro registros y basándose en qué criterios? Por ejemplo, el código `11` tiene estos ids: `1,3,7,8,11` ¿qué cuatro de esos ids deben mostrarse y por qué?

Comment: @Puntay revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: El criterio para mostrarlos es por el id ascendente. Y en el caso del ejemplo deben ser cuatro porque la suma de los importes contiene el valor del $total. Y en el código que pusiste, quiero cambiarlo para que aparezca el importe.

Comment: @Puntay revisa la nueva edición.

Comment: Se obtiene lo que se tiene, pero tienes razón, hay que cambiar la lógica del programa.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es mostrar X registros asociados a una ID hasta alcanzar un total, lo más sencillo es que obtengas todos los registros asociados a dicha ID con SQL para luego con PHP recorrerlos y obtener solo aquellos que necesites:

Como el código que indicaste para ejecutar la base de datos está incompleto, voy a partir de un array como el que debería devolver la consulta SQL para proponer la solución:

```
function listar($codigo, $total) {
   // .. el código con el que obtienes los datos iría aquí     

  // La consulta a la base de datos devolvería un array como este
  $dbResult = [
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 5],
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 10],
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 15],
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 20],
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 25],
    ['id' => 1, 'importe' => 30]
  ];

  // Añadimos un contador para ir sumando importes y creamos un array con las líneas que vamos a devolver
  $count  = 0;
  $result = [];

  // Recorremos los resultados
  foreach ($dbResult as $row) {
    // Si el contador es igual o mayor que el importe total pasado a la función, salimos del bucle devolviendo el resultado
    if ($count >= $total) {
      return $result;
    }

    // Si no, añadimos la fila al resultado y sumamos su importe al contador
    $result[] = $row;
    $count   += $row['importe'];
  }
}

// Test
print_r(listar(1, 35));
print_r(listar(1, 70));
```